# errors in my +,- calculating game program

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm a beginner of android studio and I want to make a simple calculating game program.(1~99 / +, -)
But there's so much errors in this program and I don't know what should be fixed.
Errors: illegal start of type /  expected / ';' expected / class, interface, or enum expected
(Especially 'class, interface, or enum expected' errors are so much)
Here's the code of program

```
package com.example.hello;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Random ran=new Random();
    int n1=ran.nextInt(98)+1;
    int n2=ran.nextInt(98)+1;
    int n3=ran.nextInt(2);
    int answer=0;
    int acnt=0;
    int qcnt=0;

    if(n3==0){
        answer = n1 + n2;
        qcnt++;
    }
    else{
        answer=n1-n2;
        qcnt++;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Question);
        final TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        final EditText eText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Answer);
        Button bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        Button bt2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt2);
        Button bt3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.endbt);

        if (n3==0)
            tv.setText(n1+"+"+n2+"=");
        else
            tv.setText(n1+"-"+n2+"=");

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str = eText.getText().toString();
                if (Integer.parseInt(str) == answer){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    acnt++;
                }
                else if (str==null)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write the anser.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong. The answer is "+answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int n1=ran.nextInt(98)+1;
                int n2=ran.nextInt(98)+1;
                int n3=ran.nextInt(98)+1;
                if (n3==0){
                    answer = n1 + n2;
                    tv.setText(n1+"+"+n2+"=");
                    qcnt++;
                }
                else{
                    answer=n1-n2;
                    tv.setText(n1+"-"+n2+"=");
                    qcnt++;
                }
            }
        });

        bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv2.setText(acnt+"/"+qcnt+", percentage: "+(float)(acnt/qcnt)+"%");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, it would be great if you could include the error messages. That might help to spot the problems.

Comment: Please move all codes into onCreate method.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue not allowing for the code to compile is the `if else` statement being placed directly in the class:

```
if (n3 == 0) {
    answer = n1 + n2;
    qcnt++;
} else {
    answer = n1 - n2;
    qcnt++;
}
```

It needs to be placed within A) an initializer block or B) a method:

A)

```
{
    if (n3 == 0) {
        answer = n1 + n2;
        qcnt++;
    } else {
        answer = n1 - n2;
        qcnt++;
    }
}
```

B)

```
@Override                                                            
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                              
                                                                     
    if (n3 == 0) {                                                   
        answer = n1 + n2;                                            
        qcnt++;                                                      
    } else {                                                         
        answer = n1 - n2;                                            
        qcnt++;                                                      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my previous answer focusing on the compilation error, here below is an improved version of your code.

The **3 main modifications**:

1. creating a method for question creation (i.e. `makeNewQuestion`) called in the `onCreate` method (to make the initial question) and `onClick` method (to make a new question after button click)
2. creating a method for displaying the question (`displayQuestion(TextView tv)` also called in `onCreate` and `onClick` methods), where the original 'if' condition was replaced by a 'ternary operator'
3. within the `n1` and `n2` variable assignments, replacing  `ran.nextInt(98) + 1`  by  `ran.nextInt(99) + 1`, as the upper bound in `@param bound` is excluding the bound value

```
package com.example.hello;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
    int answer;
    int acnt;
    int qcnt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Question);
        final TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        final EditText eText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Answer);
        Button bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        Button bt2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt2);
        Button bt3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.endbt);

        makeNewQuestion();
        displayQuestion(tv);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String str = eText.getText().toString();
                if (Integer.parseInt(str) == answer) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    acnt++;
                } else if (str == null)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write the answer.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong. The answer is " + answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                makeNewQuestion();
                displayQuestion(tv);
            }
        });

        bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv2.setText(acnt + "/" + qcnt + ", percentage: " + (float) (acnt / qcnt) + "%");
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayQuestion(TextView tv) {
        String operator = (n3 == 0) ? "+" : "-";
        tv.setText(n1 + operator + n2 + "=");
    }

    private void makeNewQuestion() {
        n1 = ran.nextInt(99) + 1;
        n2 = ran.nextInt(99) + 1;
        n3 = ran.nextInt(2);
        qcnt++;

        if (n3 == 0) {
            answer = n1 + n2;
        } else {
            answer = n1 - n2;
        }
    }
}
```